# Why can't I set SelectedIndex on a data-bound ComboBox?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml, combobox

I have two ComboBox elements, one with databinding and one without.

On the one without I can set the SelectedIndex fine.

But on the one that is databound, if I set the SelectedIndex, it says, "**AG_E_INVALID_ARGUMENT**".

But if I set it to a value in the ViewModel (SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCustomerIndex}") then it says "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**."

**Does anyone know why I can't just set a SelectedIndex on a ComboBox that is data bound like this?**

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#eee" >
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="top" Width="250">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedIndex="0"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateCustomers}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <ComboBox x:Name="WhichNumber" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="One"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Two"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Three"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using TestBasics737.Models;

namespace TestBasics737.ViewModels
{
    public class PageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public PageViewModel()
        {
            Customers.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Smith" });
            Customers.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Angie", LastName = "Smithton" });

            SelectedCustomerIndex = 0;

        }



        #region ViewModelProperty: SelectedCustomerIndex
        private int _selectedCustomerIndex = 0;
        public int SelectedCustomerIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedCustomerIndex;
            }

            set
            {
                _selectedCustomerIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomerIndex");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ViewModelProperty: Customers
        private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
        {
            get
            {
                return _customers;
            }

            set
            {
                _customers = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region PropertChanged Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedItem really likes to be [two-way bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855519/binding-combobox-selecteditem-in-silverlight).